# AngularJs accessing scope outside from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change the value of variables in html with the help of AngularJS. For that I know that onclick function can be called which will enable us to change the value:
The javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('graphApp', []);
app.controller('graphAppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.names= {0:{'Name':'John','Country':'albania'}};
        $scope.count++;
        keyword_type = 1
        check();

    }
});
```

Now I want to change the value of variable names from outside the function after performing some calculations. What is the procedure for that?

HTML :

```
<div id="search-container" ng-app="graphApp" ng-controller="graphAppCtrl">
          <tabs id="mainTabs">
                <pane title="Name search">

                    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
                    <button ng-click="myFunction()">Search</button>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Index</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>ID</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                            <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <p ng-bind="check"></p>
                </pane>
```

getting value from this function :

```
function WebSocketTest(keyword_or_query,keywordtype) {

       var object_of_each_pair = [];

        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            //messageContainer.innerHTML = "WebSocket is supported by your Browser!";
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/websocket");
            ws.onopen = function() {
                var message=[]
                message = keyword_or_query + 'XXXX' + keywordtype
                ws.send(message);
            };
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 

                var received_msg = evt.data;
                node_id = received_msg
             }
```

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: hi please clarify when do you want to change the value,there should some event when value has to change either on page load or on click of some button or frequently after some time event. I want to know exactly on what event you want to change the value

Comment: I make an external request to neo4j data base and from that I get the result which I have to show on over here. I am doing it by tornado server which is jandling everything at back end

Comment: I also added the WebSocketTest code from where I want to get the value from:  ws.onmessage = function (evt)

Comment: if WebSocketTest() is in same controller then in that function itself you can assign values to you scope variable and it will work. If it is in different controller the you can use $rootScope.$broadcast

Comment: @VickyKumar  Can you please tell how it can be implemented? It is in different controller

Comment: ok @Zohair let me make a code pen for this, in your controller you have injected $scope with that you also inject $rootscope like this

app.controller('graphAppCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/5qqy2oz5/))

---

Angular environment:

```
app.controller('graphAppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.some_info = 'foo';
});
```

---

This is how you retrieve `scope` from outside Angular environment:

```
// in your case
var where_you_put_ng_app = document.getElementById("search-container");
var scope = angular.element(where_you_put_ng_app).scope();

// from here you can modify your $scope variables
scope.some_info = '.....';
```

Comment: Error : Cannot read property 'names' of undefined                                         I I did it like this                                                                                                                var graphApp = document.documentElement; // IF <html>
 var scope = angular.element(graphApp).scope();  And then : scope.names[0].Name = object_of_each_pair in WebSocketTest () Function

Comment: can you please tell me what do you mean by **where_you_put_ng_app**

Comment: @ZohairZahid `document.getElementById("search-container")`.

Comment: . Error scope is undefined. I even checked by logging it in console

Comment: Thanks alot @Jonatas Walker

Answer (score 0):

in case your $scope.myFunction() and WebSocketTest() both are in same controller then just after getting response you can assign value to $scope.names

In case both are in different controller then after getting value in WebSocketTest() you can use $rootScope.$broadcast like this

suppose you got your value in

```
currentVariable//just name of variable
```

then

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("broadCastonmessage",currentVariable)
//from here we will broadcast once we got the value
```

now in you controller

```
$rootScope.$on('broadCastonmessage',function($event,Value){
 //this part will be executed whenever broadcast is done
 //now value can be assigned to scope variable
 $scope.names =value
})
```

here is one simple example showing how to use broadcast to assign a changed variable to some other variable in other scope hope it will prove helpful to you

http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/Eyyzvx

Comment: ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: you need to provide dependency of rootScope in your controller

Comment: $rootScope.$on('broadCastonmessage',function(Value){
 //this part will be executed whenever broadcast is done
 //now value can be assigned to scope variable
 $scope.names =value
})   I added this in controller

Comment: Still the same error  
ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Comment: i hope the controller from which broadcast is being done in that controller rootScope is injected properly. for correct syntax please see the code pen there $broadcast is working fine you can implement in same way

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you want to change your controller's variable values from outside angularjs , in javascript.

if that so, you should get the current scope and `$apply` the changes, like this:

```
           var scope = angular.element($("any class name from your DOM")).scope();

                //in order to update the new values to the controller , '$apply'
                scope.$apply(function () {
                     //here you can call and change any variable from your controller
                     scope.names= {0:{'Name':'xxxx','Country':'xxxx'}};
                });
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You need jquery. import it on the header

Comment: Thanks. Now another probelm : (index):738 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined

Comment: I checked on console as well the scope is undefined in the WebSocketTest from where I want to get the value

Comment: This show to me that you didnt manage to get the scope. So add a class name on your DOM like ,  <tabs id="mainTabs"> ==> <tabs id="mainTabs" class="mytabs">   and use it to get the scope, like this :  var scope = angular.element($(".mytabs")).scope();     Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still  scope is undefined. Even I checked it in the controller as well.